# Unable to build Blazor project after upgrading to 0.6.0

Tags: blazor

I just downloaded the latest version of Blazor (0.6.0). I've followed the instructions to be found here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aspnet.blazor

Then, in Visual Studio, I created a new Blazor project. Before making any changes, I built the template, got the following message, and my build failed. My existing Blazor 0.5.0 apps are also failing with the same error. Any thoughts?

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB3073 The command "dotnet "C:\Users\peter.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.build\0.6.0\targets../tools/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Build.dll" write-boot-json "obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\BlazorAndJS3.dll" --references "C:\Users\peter\Source\Repos\BlazorAndJS3\BlazorAndJS3\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\blazor\bootjson-references.txt" --embedded-resources "C:\Users\peter\Source\Repos\BlazorAndJS3\BlazorAndJS3\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\blazor\embedded.resources.txt" --linker-enabled --output "C:\Users\peter\Source\Repos\BlazorAndJS3\BlazorAndJS3\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\blazor\blazor.boot.json"" exited with code -2147450730.  BlazorAndJS3    C:\Users\peter.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.build\0.6.0\targets\Blazor.MonoRuntime.targets   640

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, I upgraded to .net core sdk 2.1 (v2.1.403) that I took from "https://www.microsoft.com/net/download" and it fixed my build.

Eric

Comment: Excellent! Solved my problem. And I was dumb about it, too -- I was so sure that I had the 2.1 sdk that I didn't check. Thanks.